# Sharepoint 2010 Excel Web Part displaying Pivot Table colors incorrectly

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, pivot-table

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site with an Excel Web Part being used to embed a pivot table into a page.  When first set up yesterday it worked perfectly, exactly as expected.  However, today one of the users clicked on the Row Labels filter button and all of the colors changed.

Above is the table is it appears in the Excel document, below is the table as it appears in Sharepoint.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVqGe.png

I have already tried the following fixes:

Uploaded a new copy of the excel document
Changed the theme of the table in excel
Deleted the web part from the page and recreated it

Nothing has worked.

Please help

Comment: The problem occurs in both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

Comment: I mitigated the problem for the time being by switching the theme to the default "blank" theme.  It is at least readable for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to resolve the problem by restarting the Excel Services component of Sharepoint 2010.